# Tried nearly everything to fix my overheating PC, not sure what to do

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, cpu, temperature, nvidia-geforce

I own this laptop: https://compareindia.news18.com/specification/laptops/hcl-me-xite-m-2035-b/270022

Using it for 5 years, ran without any problems, until about 3 months ago, where it gradually started to overheat and often shut down quickly - right now it can barely run YouTube for a minute before it's off.

CPU temperature is around 70-75 Celsius and the GPU is about 75-80 Celsius when the browser is open with a single tab - no gaming or anything. I've checked and got it confirmed that it's not:

- software or operating system
- the fan/ventilation
- thermal grease
- poor ventilation
- battery/charger/power issues
- dust etc

I took it to a repair shop and they said it's probably the Nvidia graphics chip over heating, but they seem reluctant to give me a confirmation that putting money to change it will fix the issue. So I'm afraid of replacing the chip only to find that the problem is something else(maybe the CPU is "dying"...? Not 100% sure what that term means)

Thoughts?

Also, could I somehow disable the chip as a workaround? Tried messing around the BIOS, didn't find anything.

Comment: Have you tried disabling the graphics card, or booting from a usb drive ? If it still over heats maybe the electronics are simply too old. The more you use the electronic devices, the more they "age", and the more they "age" the more they over-heat.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t agree with the comment that the more you use an electronic device, the more it overheats. Electronics don’t start running hotter just because they are older. However, cooling systems do wear out.

It’s best to have a clear idea of the thermal characteristics of the laptop. To say it is “overheating” doesn’t really say much. What is overheating? The temperatures you do list don’t show an overheating CPU or GPU.

So, I would recommend downloading a trial of Aida64. You can install it and run the “Burn-in Test.” This will load test the system components and chart the temperature. It will reveal overheating, and throttling caused by overheating. Your laptop may even shut off.

It is also good to look at how fast the temperature rises after starting the load test. If the temperature jumps up super high within a few seconds, this is an indicator the heat pipe is bad or is not seated on the CPU properly. If it rises slowly (30 seconds or more), but still overheats, then the problem is probably the fan or blocked cooling fins. But, it’s important to know what is normal and what is overheating. Obviously, after a repair, the thermal profile should be significantly improved.

No, your laptop is not overheating from “old” or defective electronics. It’s always the same reason, the cooling system has failed in some way. The fan is not functioning properly, the cooling fins are blocked, the heat pipe has failed, or the heatsink is not seated on the CPU properly. The labor to change these components can sometimes be quite high. But, the cost of the components themselves are not much. If a repair shop can’t fix those obvious issues, take it somewhere else.

Comment: It should be added that cooling system could fail at any point.  ICs and ICBs typically do not run difference as they age.  Your CPU was designed to be turned on 27/7.  There might be an expected lifespan, but that isn't typically the cause, of the problems you describe